# gnuradio error creating custom blocks with gr_modtool

Tags: linux, gnuradio

Platform: Zynq7020 Cortex A9 processors on a ZedBoard

OS : Linaro Linux

So I'm attempting to create some custom GNU Radio blocks on the ZedBoard but am receiving the following errors...

```
$ gr_modtool create fpga_accelerators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gr_modtool", line 25, in <module>
    from gnuradio.modtool import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/modtool/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from modtool_base import ModTool, ModToolException, get_class_dict
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/modtool/modtool_base.py", line 27, in <module>
    from gnuradio import gr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from runtime_swig import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/runtime_swig.py", line 26, in <module>
    _runtime_swig = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/runtime_swig.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_runtime_swig', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so.0.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file libgnuradio-pmt-3.74git.so.0.0.0 is in my PATH variable so I'm not sure what the issue is...

```
$ sudo find ./ -name "libgnuradio-pmt*"
./usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so.0
./usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so
./usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so.0.0.0
./usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-pmt.so
./home/linaro/gnuradio/build/gnuradio-runtime/lib/pmt/libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so.0
./home/linaro/gnuradio/build/gnuradio-runtime/lib/pmt/libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so
./home/linaro/gnuradio/build/gnuradio-runtime/lib/pmt/libgnuradio-pmt-3.7.4git.so.0.0.0
./home/linaro/gnuradio/build/gnuradio-runtime/lib/pmt/libgnuradio-pmt.so
```

Comment: Did you very recently build GNU Radio? Maybe a `sudo ldconfig` would help?

Comment: That fixed it. So ldconfig maintains the shared library cache according to google? What does that actually do? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds good. Check out `man ldconfig`, it has a nice short and clear description of what it does. As far as why this was necessary, it was just one of those rare cases where you built an actual library from source and had to be aware of some of the little things that your distro's package manager handles for you most of the time. Enjoy GNU Radio and come back if you run into any more problems!